# error adding symbols while compiling gdcm

Tags: gcc, gdcm

I wanted to compile gdcm from source code on eOS 0.3/Ubuntu 14.04, and add python support. Therefore I installed swig, and afterwards ran ccmake (for configuring the make file) and make. Unfortunately I get the error:

```
../../bin/libgdcmMEXD.a: error adding symbols
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to build using shared libs instead. From the `ccmake` interface you should see something like

```
GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS  ON
```

Then rebuild:

```
$ make clean && make
```